# Как обновить содержимое примонтированного volume в docker service?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Есть `docker-compose.yml` файл:

```
version: "3.5"

services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        depends_on:
            - my-app
            - my-admin
        ports: 
            - 80:80
        volumes:
            - /home/project/data/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - /home/project/public:/var/public
            - my-admin-volume:/usr/src/app
        networks:
            - my-network
        deploy:
            placement:
                constraints: [node.role == manager]

    my-admin:
        image: my-admin
        env_file:
            - /home/project/ucell.env
        ports:
            - 9000:9000
        depends_on:
            - mariadb
            - redis
            - mongodb
        working_dir: /usr/src/app
        volumes:
            - /home/project/data/log:/var/log/container
            - /home/project/public:/usr/src/app/storage/app/public
            - my-admin-volume:/usr/src/app
        networks:
            - my-network

volumes:
    my-admin-volume:

networks:
    my-network:
```

Запускаю `docker stack` командой:

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml prod
```

Все создается и работает хорошо. Но когда надо обновить образ my-admin, я запускаю команду:

```
docker service update --image my-admin:v2 prod_my-admin --force
```

(v2 здесь к примеру).
То `volume` с названием `prod_my-admin-volume` содержит старые файлы из старого образа `my-admin:v1.` (При создание стека в название `volume docker` сам добавляет префикс `prod_`)
Для того чтоб обновить содержимого `volume` делаю:

```
docker service update --mount-add type=volume,source=prod_my-admin-volume,target=/usr/src/app prod_my-admin
docker service update --mount-add type=volume,source=prod_my-admin-volume,target=/usr/src/app prod_nginx
```

Но все равно не обновляется.
Но если удалить запущенный стек, volume с названием prod_my-admin-volume
и заново создать стек то все новые файлы видны.

Вопрос: Как можно обновить содержимое примонтированного `volume` без пересоздания стека? Кто нибудь сталкивался с такой ситуацией? Если можно укажите в какую сторону копать?

Comment: Вы уверены, что вам нужно класть в volume то, что должно обновляться?

Comment: @etki Да, так как там очень много css, js и других статических файлов который генерируется при создании образа. В новом образе добавляется новые файлы.

Comment: а как это связано с volume?

Comment: Сделано так чтобы nginx мог брать статику с my-admin образа.

Comment: Ну в общем докер так не работает. Вам нужно просто из одного источника собирать два контейнера, один с бэкендом, другой со статикой.